# JSR-303 Append Default Validation Message

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I am using the Apache Bean Validation implementation of JSR-303 and was curious if there is a way to append a message to the default message that is defined in the `ValidationMessages.propeties` file.

I.E. `@NotNull(message="Object objectField name {message}")`

Output : Object objectField name may not be null

Where message would simply append the default message

Is this possible using the Apache Bean Validation 0.3 or Hibernate Validation 4.1.0-Final APIs???

Or am I forced to do something like this:

```
ValidationMessage.properites
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=may not be null
```

Code :

```
@NotNull(message="Object objectField name {javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}")
```

Which just seems very verbose.

Answer (score 2):

No.  There's no way to do that.

See the JSR-303, section 4.3.1.1 for more information.

You could do this:

ValidationMessage.properties

```
custom.message=Object objectField name {javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}
```

Code

```
@NotNull(message="{custom.message}")
```

And get what you want.  Custom message properties are (according to the JSR) supposed to be recursively resolved.  I do not know how compatible the Apache Validator is at this time but I can tell you that the Hibernate Validator (being 100% TCK compliant) will do that.